# How can I remove the <td> tag from the data frame

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

[Here is my code in github](https://github.com/meezanmalek/coronavirus_data/blob/master/corona_virus.py)

[Here is my output in excel file from that dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoVXC.png)

---

**How i can remove those  tags ???**

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this with a one liner using the bs4's `get_text()` function

```
list_of_td=r.find_all('td') #it will return the list of td's from a particular tr
```

becomes

```
list_of_td = [td.get_text() for td in r.find_all('td')]
```